# Keras generator

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I wrote my generator, but I get an error at the output

```
def batch_generator(X_data, y_data, batch_size):
    samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
    number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
    counter=0
    index = np.arange(np.shape(y_data)[0])
    while 1:
        index_batch = index[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
        X_batch = X_data[index_batch,:].toarray()
        y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch,y_batch
        if (counter > number_of_batches):
            counter=0
```

Error on line:
y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: knows anyone???

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your array to a `list`. Since `index()` is a method of type `list` not `numpy.ndarray`. Please try:

```
y_data.tolist().index(index_batch)
```

Comment: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()